# Retrieve Data from a csv file and assign to a SSIS Variable

Tags: c#, ssis-2012

Good day! Basically I am importing data from CSV file but would like to assign the value in cell C2 to a variable to be used in the SSIS flow. I know that this can be done using Script Task but I'm no c# person.

Appreciate any help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWtpK.jpg)

Comment: Where does C# come into this? Why can't you just read the data from the datasource in SSIS?

Comment: check this out it might get you going [using Excel with SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403358.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

use record set as destination assign valuues to obj type variable and later using for each loop (for each ADO Enumerator u can assign the values to separate variales)